# How to play local M3u8 files on iOS through GCDWebServer

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm attempting to run a local GCDWebServer to serve up an M3U8 file I have stored locally from a server. I parsed the file and saved each .ts file to local storage. Now I'm trying to serve that file up through a local web server, but I'm unable to get the file to play using either MPMoviePlayerController or AVPlayerViewController.

Here is my server code:

```
webServer = [[GCDWebServer alloc] init];

[webServer addDefaultHandlerForMethod:@"GET"
                         requestClass:[GCDWebServerRequest class]
                         processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {

                             NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                             NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                             NSString *textPath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"localPlaylist.m3u8"];
                             return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:textPath] contentType:@".m3u8"];
                         }];

[webServer startWithPort:8080 bonjourName:nil];
```

and my subsequent attempt to play the code:

```
 AVPlayerViewController *newPlayer = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
newPlayer.player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:webServer.serverURL];
[self presentViewController:newPlayer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong in the way I'm serving up the local m3u8 file? Also, is running a local web server a secure way to host content?

Comment: Have you got any success to play locally saved m3u8 file and encrypted/decrypted chunks? I am currently working on same flow, need some guidance.

Answer (score 3):

change your **content-type** to **application/vnd.apple.mpegurl** as stated in [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-08) section **3.1**

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> NSString *somePath = @"path/to/folder/with/your/playlist";
>
> GCDWebServer *webServer = [[GCDWebServer alloc] init];
> [webServer addGETHandlerForBasePath:@"/" directoryPath:somePath indexFilename:nil cacheAge:3600 allowRangeRequests:YES];
> [webServer start];
> ```

**Edit:**

With this setup of webserver, request to the server address will return list of files of folder which was pointed out in `directoryPath`. So link for launching HLS stream will look like `http://server_local_address/playlist.m3u8`